# How to use AppleScript to create a new Rich Text Format file from clipboard text?

Tags: macos, applescript, copy-paste, text

I have an Automator Service that takes the current text on the clipboard and writes it to a new .txt file. This is executed simply with the following piece of AppleScript code:

```
do shell script "pbpaste > /path/to/your/clipboard-file.txt"
```

This code is from the following Stack Overflow answer:

[AppleScript to paste text from clipboard into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976338/applescript-to-paste-text-from-clipboard-into-a-file/9977677#9977677)

However, this code converts the clipboard contents to plain text, removing all of the text's formatting.

Is it possible to use AppleScript to write the clipboard contents to an .rtf or .rtfd file, while preserving the original formatting of the clipboard contents? By original formatting, I am referring to stylistic data such as typographical emphasis (bold, italics, underline), font size, and text color.

On a whim, I tried the following command:

```
do shell script "pbpaste > /path/to/your/clipboard-file.rtf"
```

But this command resulted in an .rtf file that my computer was unable to read or open.

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with both RTF and HTML Clipboard content.

Comment: Did my updated answer work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer has been updated to reflect *rubik's sphere's* misunderstanding between what Rich Text is (what was originally asked about) and what's actually being worked with from Google Chrome, being HTML. (See comments moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45233/discussion-on-answer-by-user3439894-how-to-use-applescript-to-create-a-new-rich).)

I'm leaving the original answer as is, and below this new content, as it does technically answer the original question as asked. It also contains relevant information to the overall process of dealing with Clipboard content in the context of the original and modified question.

The *code* below is example *code* to be tested and run within (Apple) Script Editor, as aside from the first sentence in the question, no explicit and specific usage within Automator has, yet, been given. The *code* may need to be edited to work within the unknown usage in Automator. That said, as written, if the entire *script* below was placed by itself into a Run AppleScript action, by itself, in Automator... it works as is. If using only segments of the *code*, some changes to the existing *code* could need to be made.

The *code* below contains sufficient commenting so as to understand overall what the *script* is doing.

---

```
--        # 
--        # Change the 'New RichText Filename.rtf' name to the wanted filename for the target file.
--        # Make sure you leave the double-quotes even if the filename does not contain spaces!
--        # Note that '(path to desktop as text)' can also be modified as needed, e.g. changed to,
--        # '(path to documents folder as text)' or the entire segment after 'set theRichTextFileName to'
--        # can be a fully qualified POSIX pathname, e.g.: set theRichTextFileName to "/path/to/filename.rtf"
--        #  

set theRichTextFileName to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "New RichText Filename.rtf"


--    #        THE REMAINING CODE SHOULD NOT NEED TO BE MODIFIED.
--    # 
--    #     Note: This code, as is, works as written and intended when run from within (Apple) Script Editor.
--    #     Some AppleScript code when wrapped in Automator may not work the same as in (Apple) Script Editor.
--    #     In cases where is does not work from a Run AppleScript action in Automator, editing will be required.
--    # 
--    #     This AppleScript code preforms the following actions, sans errors caught during File I/O operations.
--    # 
--    # 1. See it the target file exists and prompts to be overwritten if it does. If yes is selected, it continues.
--    # 
--    # 2. If the Clipboard contains RTF content, writes it to the target file using plain AppleScript.
--    # 
--    # 3. If the Clipboard contains HTML content, writes it to the target file as RTF using a 'do shell script' command.
--    # 
--    # 4. If the Clipboard does not contain any RTF/HTML content, notify the user. 
--
--        #    Notes: The 'do shell script' makes use of the following:
--        #
--        #    'osascript' to get the HTML content from the Clipboard.
--        #    The content is a Hex stream within a data wrapper and
--        #    'awk' will be used to remove/replace the data wrapper.
--        #
--        #    'awk' to remove the data wrapper from 'osascript' output
--        #    replacing it with proper HTML opening/closing Tags to
--        #    ensure it actually gets processed by 'textutil' after 'xxd'.
--        #    Without the HTML opening/closing Tags 'textutil' does not 
--        #    properly, within limits, convert the HTML Clipboard content to RTF.
--        #
--        #    'xxd' to convert the Hex data from 'osascript/awk' to ASCII text.
--        #
--        #    'textutil' to convert the ASCII text HTML from 'xxd' to RTF
--        #    formatted data and write it to the target file.


tell application "Finder"

    if exists theRichTextFileName as POSIX file then
        tell current application
            display dialog "The file \"" & theRichTextFileName & "\" already exists!" & "\n\n" & "Do you want to overwrite the file?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 1 with title "File Already Exists..." with icon caution

            if the button returned of the result is "No" then
                return
            else
                tell application "Finder"
                    delete the file (theRichTextFileName as POSIX file)
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    end if

    tell current application

        --    # Find out what class types are available for the Clipboard content
        --    # and use this information to determine which action will be taken.

        set cbInfo to get (clipboard info) as string

        if cbInfo contains "RTF" then

            try
                set richTextfromClipboard to get the clipboard as «class RTF »
            on error eStr number eNum
                display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution
                return
            end try
            try
                set fileHandle to open for access theRichTextFileName with write permission
                write richTextfromClipboard to fileHandle
                close access fileHandle
            on error eStr number eNum
                display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon caution
                try
                    close access fileHandle
                end try
            end try

        else if cbInfo contains "HTML" then

            try
                do shell script "osascript -e 'try' -e 'get the clipboard as «class HTML»' -e 'end try' | awk '{sub(/«data HTML/, \"3C68746D6C3E\") sub(/»/, \"3C2F68746D6C3E\")} {print}' | xxd -r -p | textutil -convert rtf -stdin -stdout > " & quoted form of theRichTextFileName
            on error eStr number eNum
                display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution
            end try

        else

            display dialog "The Clipboard does not contain\nany usable RTF/HTML content!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "No RTF/HTML Content on Clipboard..." with icon caution

        end if

    end tell

end tell
```

---

**Original answer to the original question asked:**

To get **Rich Text** *content* from the **Clipboard** into a *file* using **AppleScript**, it's a bit more complex then a simple `do shell script` *command*.

The example **AppleScript** *code* below will, if the target *file* doesn't already exist and if **Rich Text** *content* exists on the **Clipboard**, write it to a *file*. It will have all the *attributes* as the **RichText** *content* on the **Clipboard** has, as it did when copied to the **Clipboard**.

Open **Script Editor** and copy and paste the *code* below into a new **Untitled** document and then run it from **Script Editor**, reviewing the *output* in **Events/Replies**. Run it a couple of times, with and without **Rich Text** *content* on the **Clipboard** and with and without the existence of the *file*, on the hard drive, defined by `set theRichTextFileName ...` at the start of the *script*.

You'll see the *code* makes sure the *file* doesn't exist, so as not to overwrite an exiting *file* of the target name and location and if the **Clipboard** doesn't contain **Rich Text** *content*, it displays a message for that too.

Now if using this in an **Automator Service** e.g., where **Service receives selected rich text**, then the *code* can be modified not to trap for an error if **Rich Text** *content* isn't on the **Clipboard** as the *service* will not appear on the **Services** *menu* if **Rich Text** is not selected in a document.  Also if you want to overwrite the target *file* at its designated location the *code* around that can be removed too. I'll give those *code* examples as well.

---

Example *code* to paste into **Script Editor** for testing and review:

```
set theRichTextFileName to POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text) & "New RichText Filename.rtf"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists theRichTextFileName as POSIX file then
        tell current application
            display dialog "The file \"" & theRichTextFileName & "\" already exists!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File Already Exists..." with icon caution
        end tell
    else
        tell current application
            try
                set richTextfromClipboard to get the clipboard as «class RTF »
            on error eStr number eNum
                display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "No Rich Text Content on Clipboard..." with icon caution
                return
            end try
            try
                set fileHandle to open for access theRichTextFileName with write permission
                write richTextfromClipboard to fileHandle
                close access fileHandle
            on error eStr number eNum
                display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon caution
                try
                    close access fileHandle
                end try
                return
            end try
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

---

Example *code* to use in an **Automator Service** e.g., where **Service receives selected rich text**:

```
set theRichTextFileName to POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text) & "New RichText Filename.rtf"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists theRichTextFileName as POSIX file then
        tell current application
            display dialog "The file \"" & theRichTextFileName & "\" already exists!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File Already Exists..." with icon caution
        end tell
    else
        tell current application
            set richTextfromClipboard to get the clipboard as «class RTF »
            set fileHandle to open for access theRichTextFileName with write permission
            write richTextfromClipboard to fileHandle
            close access fileHandle
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

---

Example *code* to use in an **Automator Service** e.g., where **Service receives selected rich text** and overwrites existing target *file*:

```
set theRichTextFileName to POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text) & "New RichText Filename.rtf"

tell current application
    set richTextfromClipboard to get the clipboard as «class RTF »
    set fileHandle to open for access theRichTextFileName with write permission
    write richTextfromClipboard to fileHandle
    close access fileHandle
end tell
```

---

The image below is of an example **Automator Service** that creates the **New RichText Filename.rtf** *file* from selected **Rich Text** from the **Create Rich Text file from Clipboard** *service* on the **Services Context menu** (by right-click) or **Application_name** > **Services** > **menu**, when **Rich Text** is selected in a document.

[image: Automator Service - Create Rich Text file from Clipboard]

---

Now these are just examples and additional logic can be coded to tailor it to meet ones needs. As an example, *code* could be added to automatically increment an existing file's name so as not to overwrite it, or prompt for a new file name and complete the operation vs. aborting with a message that the file already exists, etc.

---

**Update for use with a `do shell script` *command***:

If you really want to do it using a `do shell script` *command*, then use the following *code* while replacing `/path/to/new rich text file.rtf` with a valid *path filename* to a location you have write permissions. Note not to remove the `\"` before and after `/path/to/new rich text file.rtf` in the actual *command* as this handles the *path filename* if containing spaces. If the *path filename* does not contain spaces, then the `\"` before and after `/path/to/new rich text file.rtf` does not need to be used.

```
do shell script "osascript -e 'try' -e 'get the clipboard as «class RTF »' -e 'end try' | awk '{print substr($0, 12, length($0)-13)}' | xxd -r -p > \"/path/to/new rich text file.rtf\""
```

Here's the *command* line showing as wrapped text, for easier viewing:

`do shell script "osascript -e 'try' -e 'get the clipboard as «class RTF »' -e 'end try' | awk '{print substr($0, 12, length($0)-13)}' | xxd -r -p > \"/path/to/new rich text file.rtf\""`

- While one can copy and paste (recommend) the *code*, nonetheless here's how to type the Double Angle Quotation Marks, which are also available under Parentheses in (Special) Characters, e.g. <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in TextEdit.

  Note: Keep in mind the spacing in `«class RTF »` is meant to be offset in this use case.

  - Typing Double Angle Quotation Marks

    - « Left Double Angle Quotation Mark, press: <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>
    - » Right Double Angle Quotation Mark, press: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>

Note that, as written, this `do shell script` *command* overwrites the output file if it already exists, without prompting! It will either be a zero length file if the Clipboard does not contain any Rich Text content, otherwise the file will be of necessary length to contain the Rich Text content from the Clipboard. Obviously, additional logic could be coded into the `osascript` *command* however if you need more complexity then this you're better off using the method first presented in this answer. Or using an external script being called by `do shell script` *command* that handles all the necessary *logic* and *error handling* based on the complexity of the overall conditions this will be applied under.

- Why such complexity vs. `do shell script "pbpaste > /path/to/clipboard-file.rtf"`?

That's a good question and while `pbpaste` does have the `-Prefer {txt | rtf | ps}` option, nonetheless `pbpaste -Prefer rtf` may not output Rich Text even if it exists on the Clipboard. Or what it does output, if not ASCII Text, will not be a form of Rich Text that is understood, by e.g TextEdit, and or will not contain all the Rich Text *attributes* if any, that the Clipboard content contains.

This makes it necessary to get the Rich Text content on Clipboard in a different manner and why `get the clipboard as «class RTF »` is being used instead. When using a `do shell script` *command* with this, it requires additional processing to utilize the *data* returned, as it's in a *data wrapper* when returned and not immediately usable, thus requires further processing.

As an example, `Hello World!` in Rich Text on the Clipboard can look like this in ASCII Text:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf400
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 ComicSansMS;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\b\fs36 \cf0 Hello World!}
```

The above format unfortunately is not easily usable, if at all, in AppleScript and I believe that's why being grabbed as Hex encoded *data* is required.

- I'm basing this on the fact that even though the `get clipboard info` *command* for the Clipboard content in this example returns `{«class RTF », 265}` among the info returned, nonetheless while the ASCII Text form of this Rich Text content is 265 bytes long it is returned in Hex format at over twice the bytes with the *data wrapper*.  The fact that it's returned in Hex by `get the clipboard as «class RTF »` in both the Script Editor or using `osascript` support this supposition.

Here's the same `Hello World!` in Rich Text on the Clipboard in Hex:

`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`

However, what's returned by `get the clipboard as «class RTF »` for the `Hello World!` example above is:

`«data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»`

The Hex encoded string is in a `«data RTF »` *wrapper* which needs to be removed before converting the Hex encoded content to ASCII Text to be written to a disk file by the use of I/O Redirection, e.g.`>`, in the `do shell script` *command* example above.

So, the output of `osascript -e 'try' -e ' get the clipboard as «class RTF »' -e 'end try'` gets piped (`|`) to `awk` where it creates a substring, printing only the Hex encoded content itself, not the *data wrapper* portion, as that would not be processed properly by `xxd` in the next step of the process.

It then has to be piped (`|`) to `xxd` for conversion to `ASCII Text` to be written to a disk file using I/O Redirection, e.g.`>`, to the target *path filename*.

The image below is of [Clipboard Viewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) toggling between ASCII Text and Hex encoding views, showing `Hello World!` copied from a Rich Text Document, the one used in this example.

[image: Clipboard Viewer]

---

I hope this provides a better understanding of how AppleScript works with Rich Text content on the Clipboard, as either way conversion from a Hex encoded string to ASCII Text has to take place and this is being done transparently in the original example *code* while requiring additional processing outside of AppleScript *code* being processed by `osascript` when using the `do shell script` *command* in this context.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45233/discussion-on-answer-by-user3439894-how-to-use-applescript-to-create-a-new-rich).

Comment: @rubik's sphere, This _code_ had the same _bug_ as in your other question in that the _target file_ was being overwritten internally not deleted. I've corrected the _bug_ by adding `delete the file (theRichTextFileName as POSIX file)` within a Finder `tell` _block_ in the added _else_ _branch_ of the `if the button returned of the result is "No" then` _statement_.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, As to the modification you've asked for, I'll have to review the _code_ and see what can be done, however since this answer, now as is, actually answers the original question asked, I feel any modification should be attempted first by you and then posted as a separate question if you can't achieve your goal. IMO It's not exactly fair to come back months later requesting modifications be made to an already accepted and up-voted answer that adds additional previously unasked parameters to the original question.

Comment: I apologize. You're right. I will create a new question.

Comment: I figured out how to add blank lines to the file when I have a plain text clipboard and thus .txt file, but I couldn't figure out how to do it with an HTML or RTF clipboard. [Here's that question.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272410/i-need-help-inserting-blank-lines-into-rtf-file-with-applescript)

Answer (score 1):

RTF files, unlike TXT files, are not just plain text but have a basic structure. To create an RTF file, use the following structure (instead of just the plain text from your keyboard):

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Verdana;}}
\f0\fs16
Hello World!
}
```

Source: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html

Comment: I've edited my question so it is clearer. Do you have any idea how I can paste the clipboard text into the RTF file, and have the RTF file match the font, size, color, etc. of the clipboard text?

Comment: Pretty sure what he's saying is that if you put that metadata in a plain text file, and give that the extension .rtf, then you have a valid .rtf file.

Comment: @JonathanWarner I am indeed.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere Just replace Hello World with your clipboard text and create the file, the font of the copied text should override the default there of Verdana.

Comment: @John Ramos, In your comment you said `... I am indeed" to JonathanWarner's comment however, how your answer is written, that really isn't implied well, much less it gives no practical example of how to apply it in _coded_ format, which would have been a better answer then it was and no ambiguity about what you meant. However, rubik's sphere does not want to take plain text from the clipboard and make it rich text, he wants the rich text that is there, written to a disk file so it maintains all the rich text attributes it already has, not ones you'd have to manually code to employ your answer.

Comment: @user3439894 My answer was just a good starting point, maybe not a complete answer as I don't do Applescripts. My best guess is that the rich text attributes of the clipboard text will override the chosen font, color, and size settings and will work exactly as the OP wants. If my answer isn't satisfactory, I think Applescript might not be able to achieve this, and making an app in Xcode might be necessary. If that's the case, Stack Overflow is a good place for this question.

Comment: So I just hope that @rubik'ssphere at least tries what I have here.

Comment: @John Ramos, you said, "_If my answer isn't satisfactory, I think Applescript might not be able to achieve this, and making an app in Xcode might be necessary._" Did you read my answer? Of course it can be done in AppleScript as I wouldn't have provided the AppleScript answer I did, if it couldn't. I think the problem is as you said ,"_as I don't do Applescripts_" and herein lies the issue as you don't ever realize or understand why what you wrote for an answer isn't usable in the context of the information presented within the OP. Continued in next comment...

Comment: As to "_So I just hope that @rubik'ssphere at least tries what I have here._", well sorry to say but it's just not usable in the context asked for! When you do not understand the subject matter, in this case AppleScript, and how it works, especially in reference to the context requested, it might be best not to try an answer the question. I'm really not trying to be hard on you or upset you with what I've said and I believe if you understood AppleScript and the context of how it applies to the information presented in the OP you'd understand and wouldn't have post what you did to begin with.

Comment: @user3439894 OK, I just wanted to provide some info on the structure of RTF files, because that seems more like what's being asked here than specifically AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's functions based on the answer by user3439894 for printing the rich text version of the clipboard converted to HTML or the HTML version of the clipboard. The HTML version of the clipboard is included for text copied from a web view.

`ppr(){ osascript -e'the clipboard as"RTF "'|sed 's/«data RTF //;s/»//'|xxd -r -p|textutil -convert html -stdin -stdout; }`

`pph(){ osascript -e'the clipboard as"HTML"'|sed 's/«data HTML//;s/»//'|xxd -r -p; }`

The `sed` commands above can also be replaced with `ruby -lpe'$_=$_[10..-2]'` (even though that selects the wrong byte positions in the C locale).

In older versions of OS X `pbpaste -Prefer rtf` printed the RTF version of the clipboard but now it just seems to print plain text.