# Working with Apple HTML class data in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, unix

I saw the following line of code in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251490/44531) on AppleScript coding of HTML class data.

```
do shell script "osascript -e 'try' -e 'get the clipboard as «class HTML»' -e 'end try' | awk '{sub(/«data HTML/, \"3C68746D6C3E\") sub(/»/, \"3C2F68746D6C3E\")} {print}' | xxd -r -p | textutil -convert rtf -stdin -stdout > " & quoted form of theRichTextFileName
```

I assume the `awk` command is changing «data HTML to <html> and » to </html>.

What is the reason for doing this?
Does it mean that you do not put <html> and </html> in applescript HTML class data?

Comment: Yes, `awk` was making those substations in order for `textutil` to recognize the incoming stream of HTML data coming from  `xxd` which converted the Hex data stream to is ASCII Text equivalent.

Comment: @historystamp, **you** won't find yourself putting anything in AppleScript HTML class data, not even `<HTML>` tags, as `«class HTML»` is not a container that allows the user to manipulate its contents inside AppleScript at all. `«class HTML»` and `«class RTF »` both house an AppleScript `data` class object that is used to wrap hexadecimal representations of the HTML or rich text, which AppleScript can transport but doesn't have the tools to decode and make use of (although, that said, you can actually write the `data` object out to file and then, of course, edit the file).

Comment: @CJK glad you ferreted out my "real" question.